# python list element from decimal into string

Tags: python, string, list

I have one element in each list:

```
['39.95811864900048']
```

How can I convert into string. I tried with join:

```
"".join(item['longitude'])
```

It rounds off to 2 decimals and returns

```
36.95
```

What I need is a whole number as string:

```
39.95811864900048
```

Comment: `item['longitude'][0]`?

Comment: Just the same thing 36.95

Comment: What does `repr(item['longitude'])` return?

Comment: ['39.95811864900048']

Comment: Ah I figured it out. I am actually writing data to a cvs and editing in office calculator, cells are formated to round off to 2 decimals there :( Everything is fine with joining and accessing first element of list. Sorry and thanks for support.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just get the first element:

`a = a[0]`

#### Example

```
>>> a = ['39.95811864900048']
>>> a = a[0]
>>> a
'39.95811864900048'

>>> item['longitude'][0]
'39.95811864900048'
```